# Map Activity Action Bar Menu Buttons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to make a map activity and I want to add  2 buttons to the actionbar. I created the project with the Android Studio 0.8.4 and I'm not able to add the menu to the action bar.
pls help me

mapview.xml :

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Maps Activity.java

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener
{@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.mapmenu, menu);

        // Calling super after populating the menu is necessary here to ensure that the
        // action bar helpers have a chance to handle this event.
        return true;
}
```

mapmenu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >



<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"
    android:orderInCategory="50"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Caută"
    tools:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_cagain"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="Încearcă din nou"
    android:orderInCategory="50"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"
    tools:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Manifest :

```
<activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ferenczandras.transportmures.HARTA" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

thanks

Comment: check there is hardware menu  present in device

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: Im not getting error only not showing the items in the action bar .. if i press the setting button on the device( In a samsung galaxy S4 is the left phisical button) than appears the menu as a list

Answer (score 1):

try with -->  tools:showAsAction="always"

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"
    android:orderInCategory="50"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Caută"
    tools:showAsAction="always"/>
<item android:id="@+id/action_cagain"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:title="Încearcă din nou"
    android:orderInCategory="50"
    tools:ignore="AppCompatResource"
    tools:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: not an error message.. its not showing in the actionbar.. only as option window .. with text ]

Comment: what Theme you use to in your application?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `app:showAsAction="always"`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `tools:showAsAction="ifRoom"`, try using  `android:showAsAction="always"`

Answer (score 0):

Change your Theme... The default MAPACTIVITY THeme does not show the activity bar.. either delete them the option entirely from the  tag in your Manifest or change it to a theme that shows the actionbar.

This should be documented better, but do this and the menu will show up.